# Issue on php mysql toggle swtich change

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, cordova

I am newbie to `php` and `mysql`. Using `Cordova` plugin for `visual studio 2015` i have created a simple `mobile` application in which a user selects a `serial number` and on selecting it data is showed on the chart. Also there is a toggle switch button through which i can  change the state of the switch from `on-off` or `off-on`. While changing the state the data is inserted into DB.

Now, i want is to do is that whenever i select a serial number the last state of the toggle should be shown on the switch. Means if the user has previously change the state from `on` to `off` for a particular serial number than this change should be shown if the same serial number is selected again.

For this i have done the following

**My PHP CODE**

```
require_once('config.php');

$dsn = $_REQUEST['Device_Serial_Number'];
$cmd_Name = isset($_REQUEST['Command_Name'])?$_REQUEST['Command_Name']:"";

$sqlFet = "select ADC.Server_Device_Command_ID , ADC.Device_ID ,
ADC.Server_Command_ID as Server_Command_ID, ASD.Command_Name
from ADS_Server_Device_Command ADC
inner join ADS_Server_Command ASD on adc.Server_Command_ID = asd.Server_Command_ID
inner join ADS_Device dsn on adc.Device_ID = dsn.Device_ID
where dsn.Device_Serial_Number = '$dsn'
order by adc.Server_Device_Command_ID desc LIMIT 1";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$sqlFet);
//print_r($result);
echo json_encode( (array) $result->fetch_object());
mysqli_close($con);
echo $cmd_Name;
```

**My html(ajax) code**

```
$.ajax({
    method: "GET",
    url: "http://localhost:Port/server/toggleFetch.php",
    data: { Command_Name: tData , Device_Serial_Number: selectedVal },
    success: function (data) {
        var dt = $.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(data));
        console.log(dt);
        if (dt.Command_Name == "On") {
            $("#cmn-toggle-7").prop('checked', true);
        } else if (dt.Command_Name == "Off") {
            console.log('else');
            $("#cmn-toggle-7").prop('checked', false);
        }
    },
    error: function () {
        toastr.success('Data not fetched', '', { timeOut: 2000 })
    }
});
```

Now whenever i run the `app` this part of code executes and it always goes to the else part. i.e if my serial number's last state is `On` it shows me off as shown in the below image

[image]

In above image you can clearly see that the `command_Name = on` but still it goes to else part.

I must be doing something wrong, and that i don't know.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: try this: var `dt = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));` instead of `var dt = $.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(data));`

Comment: what Command_Name are you sending /

Comment: @kostova: thanks it's working